# cpu not fully utilized in multi-threading

Tags: java

I am writing a code for a recommendation engine which uses parallel threads for its computations. While running I get a maximum CPU usage of 265-300% (using top command) on a 8-core CPU. What I am not getting is why is it not using the full CPU even when nearly 50% of cpu is idle. The pseudo code part which uses parallelism is:

```
getRecoFromCandidates(){
    t=new Thread(new KNN(uid,profile,candidates));// does knn using closest neighbors
    rec=RecommendationsFromSet(NB_RECOMMENDATIONS,uid,candidatesI,val);// finds recommendations
    return rec;
}



RecommendationsFromSet() {
      Thread worker = new Thread(new storiesClickProcess(nbRec,candidatesI,likedSet));
      worker.start();
      threads.add(worker);
    }
    int running = 0;
    do {
      running = 0;
      for (Thread thread : threads) {
        if (thread.isAlive()) {
          running++;
        }
      }
    } while (running > 0);

    if(val==1){
    List<Story> list1 = new ArrayList<Story>();
    for(Integer sid: storiesClicks.keySet()){
        list1.add(new Story(sid,storiesClicks.get(sid)));
    }
    Collections.sort(list1,new StoriesList());
    for(i=0;i<nbRec;i++){
        rec.add(list1.get(i).getSid());
    }
    }



    return rec;
}


   parGetClosestNeighbor() {
      Thread worker = new Thread(new formNetworkProcess(nbFriends,networkScore[i],profile,candidatesI,candidatesISet) );
      worker.start();
      threads.add(worker);
    }
    int running = 0;
    do {
      running = 0;
      for (Thread thread : threads) {
        if (thread.isAlive()) {
          running++;
        }
      }
    } while (running > 0);

    List<Network> list = new ArrayList<Network>();

    for(i=0;i<TASK_NUM;i++){
     for(Integer sid: networkScore[i].keySet()){
        list.add(new Network(sid,networkScore[i].get(sid)));

    }
    }

    Collections.sort(list,new NetworkList());
    for(i=0;i<nbFriends;i++){
        friends.add(list.get(i).getUid());
    }

    synchronized(network.get(uid)) {
        network.get(uid).clear();
        for( i=0;i<friends.size();i++){
            network.get(uid).add(friends.get(i));
        }

    }


    return friends;
}
```

Comment: How busy is the network/memory? You're probably maxing on I/O requests and the threads wait for it to complete no utilizing the CPU during that time.

Comment: No, the threaded process in both the functions are fully independent and there are no i/o requests there. They have parameters passed which are used for the computations

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multicore CPU , top is not the best command to check CPU usage. Use sar

sar -P ALL 1 1000

This will print you the usage of all cores every 1 second for 1000 times

Further i do see synchronized keyword in your code. That could be causing contention. You can verify that by using vmstat or by this command

cat /proc/PID/status

Comment: Hi, i verified that the synchronisation is not causing any contention in this case. Also, the threads work independently but still it is not using max cpu

Comment: Can you dump the output of sar command as i mentioned above. Also how many application threads are you running ? Do you have enough threads to occupy all cores ? Also remember that there is cpu clock cycles lost even in thread context switching as well. Every context switch involves reading the complete thread context back in processor caches.

Comment: Hi, I am running 8 threads for 8 cores. Also, as I am using Macbook, the above sar command doesn't work. Using Sar 1 1000 gives average of 45-50% total CPU usage

Comment: Can you try to run it on a Linux/Windows box ? I am just wondering if OSX does some logic and prevents any thread from taking 100% of the CPU to keep the machine's liveness

Comment: I don't have linux at present but will try at some servers. As you said, OSX might do some thread management to prevent full usage. Will verify it